# How to refresh the page with nodejs after click on submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I would need a little help from you.

I have a button which copy something and that "something" should occurs on the page instantly. The problem is that the button has the functionality to copy, but right now I have to refresh the page manually to see the changes.

I dont think this is something tricky but I have tried following without success:

```
<form method="post" action="/users/copy?scene=<%= scene.id %>">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href">Copy the scene</button>
</form>
```

I mean it works if I change `"submit"` to `"button"`, but then the functionality to copy something is no longer working.

I googled, but I have not find any answer so far.

Any help would be really appreciated

So I just realized that the localhost was loading even before I added the function to refresh the page so there must be unfinished request on the server. I think it is in this function:

```
router.post('/copy', function(req,res,call) {

if( req.param('scene') !== undefined ){

db.serialize(function () {

 db.run("CREATE TABLE temp_table as SELECT * FROM scene where id=?", req.param('scene'));
 db.run("UPDATE temp_table SET id = NULL, user_id = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE email =?)",GLOBAL.email);
 db.run("INSERT INTO scene SELECT * FROM temp_table");
 db.run("DROP TABLE temp_table");
 // res.render('copy');
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    } 
});

db.close();

 }
 });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $(form).on('submit', function(){ 
        location.reload();
  });
})
```

Comment: where do you put this

Comment: @mskw you would put this inside a <script> tag in your html page or an included javascript file.

Comment: What does `$(abc).` mean? I entered the code and got `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.. Ahh, I see — JQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<button id="btn">
  Click me
</button>

$("#btn").click(function(){
  location.reload(true);
});
```

So once the btn is clicked. You reference it using jquery, then refresh the page using location.reload(true).
jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j9nftot3/

Comment: I have just edited my post, there is a different problem in that function I pasted in. It keeps loading the localhost and when I refresh the page then the changes occurs.